# Saudações em perguntas

Tags: debate, suporte

Pessoal sinceramente não sei como começar um novo *post* sem uma saudação (minhas cordiais saudações), pois eu falo para pessoas e não para máquinas que devem apenas se limitar a responder às minhas questões.

Gostaria apenas de saber porque é proibida a saudação no início de uma pergunta.

Comment: Eu já dei minha opinião sobre isso **[aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/851/74)**.

Comment: Fechei como duplicata, pois a posição oficial também está lá, na resposta do Gabe.

Comment: Você não foi muito sincero, você começou este sem saudar. Viu? É bem fácil. Mas acabou terminando agradecendo, é fácil terminar sem o agradecimento também. É só entender o contexto onde está, pessoas fazem isto.

Comment: "minhas cordiais saudações" não serve como saudação amigão @bfavaretto? Tudo bem que pode tornar meio ruidosa a questão, e até meio que entendo, porém torna(na minha opinião) a coisa muito fria, nos somo gente percebes. Chegar pra alguém e simplesmente questionar torna tudo muito frio e utilitarista. Sou de opinião que quem saudar não erra, e quem não saudar também não erra, e poderia ficar a cargo do que pergunta. Porém tu és o moderador e a tua decisão se faz sentir, sou apenas um ser mortal amigo.

Comment: Deixe sua opinião como resposta lá na outra pergunta. Existe uma certa flexibilidade na comunidade, se você argumentar bem e conseguir convencer bastante gente, pode até mudar essa regra. Minha opinião (não é "decisão"!), deveria valer tanto quanto a de qualquer outro usuário, no entanto sei que ser moderador acaba dando mais peso ao que eu digo... Mas fique claro que quem *decidiu* isso foi a prória Stack Exchange, como você pode ver na [central de ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: Como ironia, 3 das suas 4 perguntas aqui no meta foram marcadas duplicadas, a única que não foi é justamente a que pergunta o que fazer quando a pergunta é marcada como duplicada, rs..

Comment: Meses, anos, depois que vc resolveu seu problema e esqueceu do seu post, o pessoal que topar com ele não tem nenhum interesse em saudações ou agradecimentos, quer é saber como resolver tal coisa. E vai agradecer votando positivo.

Comment: O pessoal tem um pouco de dificuldade que aqui não é um fórum ou rede social onde há conversas entre as pessoas. Eu fico imaginando que o livro didático deve ser terrível porque ele não te cumprimenta, não agradece que fez o exercício. Um blog também não faz. Reportagens também. Tutoriais. FAQs, um teste escolar idem. Perguntas e respostas também não deveriam. E aqui temos exatamente isto. Não temos pessoas confraternizando.

Comment: Na verdade, o site oferece um espaço de relax que é o [chat], lá vale falar mal do PHP, colocar GIFs, YouTubes, trocar idéias com gente de vários continentes e combinar um chopp quando coincidem as cidades.

Comment: Ops, votei em reabrir sem querer.

Comment: @Math, de facto tens toda a razão, rs, é irônico, mas ainda não percebi a relação desta ironia com a questão atual. brasofilo de facto as pessoas anos depois o pessoal não tem nenhum interesse em saudações, a saudação nunca é (neste contexto) o objectivo final, acredito se leres os meus pequenos comentários perceberas que não meu objectivo final saudar a malta, muito menos reter agradecimento, contudo percebo o teu ponto. Até da um pouquinho de medo resistir aos gigantes do fórum, porém acredito que o meu ponto não esta totalmente errado...

Comment: Sim @brasofilo, isso não é mesmo rede social, mas agora dizer que não há conversas? Hum! rs, eu não disse que é terrível não haver saudações (conforme os exemplos), acredito que até já percebeste isso amigo, e colocares uma argumentação como está, denota uma extremidade na minha ideia, o que não é verdade, até onde vejo. Mas ok malta, percebi, NADA DE SAUDAÇÕES. Seguindo o link da central de ajuda, notei que no ponto que trata das assinaturas, taglines e cumprimentos não existe ainda uma explanação sobre saudações em si. Grato pela vossa paciência.